# Sqlite: How to select a value from a table where function(value) is another certain value?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table consisting of the following columns: 
ID, StartTime, EndTime, ...

In my Python-application these entries can be listed. You're also supposed to be able to enter a search term and only get back those entries containing this search term.

So for instance if my entries are

```
1, 05.04.2017 11:30:22, 05.04.2017 11:43:11
2, 06.04.2017 12:12:12, 06.04.2017 15:14:13
```

I can enter "05" and only get the first entry, or "04" and get both, or "11:4" and only get the first one...

The thing is that for all other parts in my application it is better to not save the formatted date in the table but the seconds (14891410etcetc) returned by time(). But that means that for the searching, I can't just execute

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE StartTime LIKE 05
```

because then it is looking for the 05 in the seconds-value.

So: Is there a way to sneak a function into the sqlite-command? So that it works like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time.strftime(StartTime) LIKE 05
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some date and time functions supported by sqlite. See https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.